# SQL Server Bulk Insert Ingore or skip last row

Tags: sql, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm using a bulk insert script to import a number of flat files into SQL Server

A few files end with

```
-----------------------------------
```

So what I want to do is or skip last row(s) or remove `------------------` in the bulk insert. Is one of these options possible?

```
SET @s = N'BULK INSERT ' + @t + '
           FROM ''' + @f + '''
           WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'',
                 ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'',
                 FIRSTROW=2)  '
```

`lastrow = 1` doesn't work

Comment: `lastrow = 1` won't work because then the bulkinsert will stop after row 1. You will first have to identify the last row in the file, and than use `lastrow = [faulty row number - 1]`

Comment: How can you identity the lastrow if the format of every file is different?

Comment: Do the bulk insert, then delete the row with `----`.

Comment: That's the problem. It doesn't insert because of the error in the last row which is `----------`

Comment: In cases like these, it's probably easiest run a powershell script to prepare the file (i.e. delete the last line). That or change the process that generates this file.

Comment: Try adding an empty newline at the end of the file

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to first bulk insert the whole file into a single column table (as `varchar(max)`). Than you can identify the last row, and use that value in your actual `bulk insert`.

This is not a very straight forward approach, but I don't think there is another (unless you write a custom solution in C# or java or whatever). Maybe you can use `SQLCMD` to first read the number of lines in the file, but I don't know how.

Please note there is a [connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/358890/need-option-to-dynamically-set-lastrow-in-bulk-insert) item which Microsoft has closed. On that page Microsoft suggests using an `openrowset` solution, could be worthwhile to try, but I doubt it would work in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

use script like next:

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#csvData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #csvData
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#csvRowCount') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #csvRowCount
CREATE TABLE #csvRowCount
(
v1 nvarchar(max) -- get only first column - for all rows in file

) 


BULK INSERT #csvRowCount
FROM 'C:\TEMP\HR_FOR_LOAD\PP_SICKLIST.CSV'
WITH
(
Firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t',
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);


declare @textRowCount int=(select count(1) from #csvRowCount) 

CREATE TABLE #csvData
(
v1 nvarchar(2000),
v2 nvarchar(2000),
v3 nvarchar(2000)
--etc

) 


declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql = '
BULK INSERT #csvData
FROM ''C:\TEMP\HR_FOR_LOAD\PP_SICKLIST.CSV''
WITH
(
Firstrow=2,
FIELDTERMINATOR = ''\t'',
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',
Lastrow = '+cast(@textRowCount as varchar(100))+'
);'



exec (@sql)

select 
v1,
v2,
v3
from #csvData
```