# Bulk insert .csv without the last row

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a .csv file with data with a number of rows (please see image)

[image: data in .csv file]

This data is provided by a third party and I cannot change the format.

I am BULK inserting this data into an SQL server table using ms SQL server management.

when i BULK insert using the following:

```
    BULK INSERT #tempDERIVEDDATA
    FROM 'C:\MyDownloads\Data.csv'
    WITH
    (FIRSTROW = 1,
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
    ERRORFILE = 'C:\MyDownloads\logfile.log')
    GO
```

I seem to get the following error:

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 236   Bulk load: An unexpected end
>   of file was encountered in the data file.  Msg 7399, Level 16, State
>   1, Line 236  The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"
>   reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the
>   error.  Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 236  Cannot fetch a row from
>   OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

When the last row which is the footer row and states the number of rows in the file is deleted the bulk insert works.  So i cannot even delete that row once putting into a table as struggling to do such.

So then I thought what if use an OPENROWSET function and count the number of rows and insert (#rows - 1) into the table?

So i tried the below to calculated the number of rows:

```
   DECLARE @lastrow INT
   SET @lastrow = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\MyDownloads\DATA1.csv', 
   FORMATFILE = 'C:\MyDownloads\format.fmt',
   MAXERRORS=10) AS  ) - 1
   SELECT @lastrow
```

The select last row should retrieve (#rows - 1) should retrieve number of rows but i get an error.

> Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 230 Bulk load: An unexpected end of
>   file was encountered in the data file. Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1,
>   Line 230 The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"
>   reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the
>   error. Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 230 Cannot fetch a row from
>   OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Format file is per below:
[image: FORMAT.FMT]

After which I decided to do above with a format file, instead SINGLE_CLOB. This time there is no errors but the file retrieves '0' lines when it should retrieve '341'.

I would appreciate if someone could assist.

Comment: Try using `LASTROW` option of the bulk insert command by specifying the last row number to read. So if you have 100 rows, you can specify `LASTROW=99`.

Comment: @Harsh that is the solution I am taking, but the number of rows in the csv files are not static.  each file is different and therefore I would need to retrieve the #rows which is was the second bit of the code is trying to achieve.

I will be using LASTROW in the BULK INSERT

Comment: Why don't you just delete the last row in the csv before doing the bulk insert?

Comment: @ejohnson, i have taken that approach using VBA to strip out the last line but since there it too many lines and about 12 files being downloaded, it is too time consuming. This method is the most efficient, it's just this problem I am experience throwing me back.  thakns for the suggestion.

Comment: I suggest two options: 1. Insert the data into a table which is all varchar and delete the last line from it. 2. Use a proper tool like powershell to delete the last line from the file before importing.

Comment: try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45689974/sql-server-bulk-insert-ingore-or-skip-last-row/72811275#72811275) get rows count and use LASTROW

Answer (score 1):

Create a temporary table with a single wide column and insert the whole row into that column for the whole file, then use select+insert to select from your temporary table, separating fields via the separator character as you select, and exclude the last row. Finally, drop the temporary table in prep for the next import.

Answer (score 0):

Consider use openrowset.

```
    create procedure [dbo].LoadData
    (
            @file nvarchar(200)=null
    )
    as
    begin
            declare @sql varchar(max)
            set @sql='INSERT INTO DBO.Table
            (
                    column1, column2
            )
            select column1
                                    ,column2
            from openrowset(bulk N''' + @file +''',
             formatfile = N''d:\xml\Table.xml'') as t1
             where not column1 like (''Total'')'

             print @sql
             exec (@sql)
    end


    --- Table.xml

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
     <RECORD>
      <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="100" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
      <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="50" COLLATION="SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"/>
     </RECORD>
     <ROW>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="column1" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
      <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="column2" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
     </ROW>
    </BCPFORMAT>
```

Comment: Hi Vicosanz, Thank you for the above, much appreciated. 

When I execute the procedure I get the below error, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: INSERT INTO #tempDERIVEDATA
            (
                    column1, column2
            )
            select column1
                                    ,column2
            from openrowset(bulk N'C:\MyDownloads\DERBMDATA\DERBMDATA1.csv' + @file +',
             formatfile = N'd:\xml\Table.xml') as t1
             where not column1 like ('FTR')

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 77
Incorrect syntax near '+'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 79
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

Comment: This is the correct form:   INSERT INTO #tempDERIVEDATA ( column1, column2 ) 
select column1 ,column2 from openrowset(bulk N'C:\MyDownloads\DERBMDATA\DERBMDATA1.csv', formatfile = N'd:\xml\Table.xml') 
as t1 where not column1 like ('FTR')

Comment: So i tried using your method and still getting the same error.  error below:

Comment: Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 27
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)"

Comment: INSERT INTO #tempDERIVEDDATA
            (c1, c2,c3, c4, c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16, c17,c18)
     select c1,c2,c3, c4, c5,c6,c7,c8,c9,c10,c11,c12,c13,c14,c15,c16, c17,c18
            from openrowset(bulk N''C:\MyDownloads\DERBMDATA\DERBMDATA1.csv'' ,
             formatfile = ''c:\xml\Table.xml'') as t1
             where not c1 like (''FTR'')'

Answer (score 0):

Hummm, I had the exact same issue back in 2015.  Do you work at CapIQ, by chance?  Anyway, I ended up creating a C# executable and running that to clean up the file before running the Bulk Insert script to load the data.  I actually saved that solution because I thought I would need it again someday.  Here is the solution.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string sourceDirectory = @"C:\ManagedCode\Downloads\";
            try
            {
                var txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(sourceDirectory);

                foreach (string currentFile in txtFiles)
                {
                    //foreach (var currentFile in files)
                    {
                        var lines = File.ReadAllLines(currentFile);

                        //Just an example of changing the filename based upon the current name
                        var targetFile = Path.ChangeExtension(currentFile, "prod.txt");
                        File.WriteAllLines(targetFile, lines.Skip(1).Take(lines.Count() - 2));
                        //};

                    }

                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }

        }
    }
}
```

You can run this executable (and any executable) on any schedule of your choosing using Windows Task Manager.

Comment: no i do not unfortunately.  I ended up using python to solve this issue, similar to what you have done on c#.  The code just downloads the data in .csv format that sql recognises.

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, Python will handle the task quite easily.  If I had to do it now, I would use Python.  Several years ago, when I was doing these things, I ddin't even know what Python was.  Lol.